# Why is this program not returning a proper answer

Tags: python

SOLVED

I wrote a python program and im trying to search for an **n** in it,
but the last 3 lines in which i'm trying trial and error method aren't giving
any output.

**Code:**

```
#3
i = 0
def rekur(x, n):
    global i
    i += 1
    #print('iteracja: ' + str(i) + '\nwartosc x = ' + str(x) + '\nwartosc y = ' + str(round(n,0))+ '\n')
    if i > 50:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return x
    else:
        if n % 3 == 0:
            k = rekur(x, round(n/3, 0))
            return round(pow(k, 3), 0)
        else:
            return round(x*rekur(x, n-1), 0)

print(rekur(3,4))

for g in range(1000):
    if round(rekur(3, g),0) == 81:
        print(g)
```

**Output:**

```
81

Process finished with exit code 0
```

These lines aren't giving any output:

```
for g in range(1000):
    if round(rekur(3, g),0) == 81:
        print(g)
```

**why is that?**

Comment: `round(rekur(3, g), 0)` is simply never equal to 81. I'd recommend evaluating `round(rekur(3, g), 0)` and `print()` the results before the `if` statement, to see what kind of output you're getting. Without looking too hard at the math, I suspect your issue has to do with `if i > 50: return 0`

Comment: Your suspects are wrong

Comment: Note for the future that we ask that a SO question have code that's as narrowly and specifically focused as possible. "Why does *this specific line of code* have output X?" is a much better question than "Why does my program have output X?", even though it requires you to do more work/investigation before opening a question, because it's more likely that someone else will be able to usefully learn from a question that's about a language feature or facility than from a question that's about someone else's specific code.

Comment: (Back when the site was new we had a specific close reason for that kind of question, "Too Localized"; today, questions that used to be closed that way are mostly considered "Too Broad").

Answer (score 0):

I found out why.
It was happening because of the  state of **i**.
now when i added

```
    if i > 50:
        i = 0
        return 0
```

it is giving me wanted answer